# How to apply gradient for a body tag has no child elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a doubt i applied linear gradient for body with no elements It's not working . But , I add any elements in the body tag it will works .

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<head>
     <style>
          body{
           background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
           background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.3));
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

**​Fiddle Link**

http://jsfiddle.net/kykPk/2/

Why is not working for empty body tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `body` tag has no elements inside it so do it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kykPk/9/)

CSS

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because an empty body will have no size(unless you size it with css), so you would not be able to see its background.